# Pivot Table Slicer Not Refreshing in Unprotected Sheet

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, slicers

I have out-dated values showing in my slicers.

I've verified nothing is protected.
Pivot tables refresh normally with no issues.
I've tried refresh all and right clicking the slicer to directly refresh. It's not grayed out, however clicking refresh does nothing.

I've also verified the "old values" are no longer in the source data.

I've even tried creating a new pivot table from scratch based on the same source data, and the old values still appear.

My source data is a table.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In slicer settings, did you select "Hide items with no data"?